# How to add a new metric in Lenskit 3.0?

Tags: metric, lenskit

I'm a student using Lenskit and I would like to implement the Intra-List similarity metric for my project. How can I implement the new TopN-metric from scratch? I'm not used to working with Gradle/Java, Implementing my own re-ranking algorithm was nice to do but I don't know how to start implementing a metric and then adding it by defining a type-name?.. I'm a little lost.

Thanks,
Diederik

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two pieces:'

1. Implement your new metric by extending`TopNMetric` (or `ListOnlyTopNMetric`).  The `X` type parameter is the type of *context object* that is used to keep track of a particular evaluation experiment (algorithm + data set combo).  You will probably need to extract whatever data you're using to compute ILS from the recommender in `createContext` and save it in your context object.  The context class is usually a static inner class of the metric class.
2. Create a properties file, `META-INF/lenskit/topn-metrics.properties`, that will show in your classpath (put it under `src/main/resources` in a standard Maven or Gradle project layout) to associate a name with your metric's class.  There you write

   `ils=my.package.ILSTOpNMetric`

This can all live in the same general project as your algorithm code.